# How does Maven know what to pull vs build?

Tags: java, maven

Let's say I have a large project and I build it locally. Half the dependencies come from Maven Central and half of them are different modules in my own project that all go into my M2.

If I get half my SNAPSHOTS being pulled from a local nexus server, but I've modified the source code of one of the SNAPSHOTS, does it pull the nexus snapshot, put it into the m2, then compile the changed version and overwrite the snapshot in my m2? Is that wasted effort?

Answer (score 1):

This is purely from my personal experience!

Let's say you have a Project A (PA) and a Project B (PB). PB has a dependency of PA via the usual maven `<dependency>` tag.

Now you modify the PA, and compile it locally. Unless you run the maven command `install`, your dependent project PB won't be able to get the modified code - as you have mentioned in your question about one of your SNAPSHOT being modified.

Once you run `install` command on maven for PA, maven will put the new artifacts to your local machine nexus repo and next time when you build PB, it will pick up the latest modified PA dependency.

Basically what maven does when you are building a project is, it goes first to your local nexus repo directory, usually but not always `<M2_HOME>\repository`, for satisfying all the dependencies, if it doesn't find then it goes to, usually, to your company local repo, and then to the public repo. All these info is configured in the `settings.xml` file of the maven.

Hence what you are doing is right thing. You have to first install your local SNAPSHOT build to your local nexus and then while compiling the dependent projects, maven will take care of the rest.

It is ***NOT*** a wasted effort, that's how maven works by design!

Comment: Nice explanation! So if I run a mvn clean install from the root of my project, it will write all the new snapshots to my m2?

Comment: Yes, when you run install on your root project, it will install all the artifacts from all sub projects plus the root project to your local repo. Check "Running Maven Tools" heading on https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html